# how to share outside of a metro app ecosystem?

Tags: windows-10

For example, I'm reading some article in the News app - the share button only lists a few metro apps and that's it.

Is there a way to straight copy it to the clipboard?

or can I install a clipboard metro app, whose sole purpose is to act as a receiver of a share action and copy it to the clipboard?

I'm just trying to share articles I read in metro apps with buddies using an IM application that does not have a metro (app) version installed.

Comment: I assume you can't just copy and paste the text?  The list, of applications, is generated by Microsoft.  What makes up that list, likely is static, of the application that Microsoft wants to support.  "can I install a clipboard metro app, whose sole purpose is to act as a receiver of a share action and copy it to the clipboard?" unlikely

Comment: Why not just print the screen & copy it like that?

Comment: I don't think it's only apps approved by microsoft - i can share to the reddit app I use. I think it is just any app that implemented that capability.

Comment: print the screen only gets a portion of the article, what I'm trying to do is send the article to a friend to read.. thing is , I like this news app - it's convenient - but when you can't share easily, that's annoying... I guess i'll just share it to the mail app and cut the url from there - not pretty but it works.